# Euler-Lagrange equation for positron from QED lagrangian

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, electrons, variational-principle, antimatter

Taking $e<0$ to be the charge of the electron, the Euler-Lagrange equation derived from taking the first variation of the $\psi$ field in the QED lagrangian $${\cal L} = - \frac 1 4 F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu} +  \bar\psi \left[(i\partial_\mu - e A_\mu)\gamma^\mu - m\right]\psi$$ gives the equation for the electron. Given that the positron is also a real particle, shouldn't the equation for the positron also emerge as an Euler-Lagrange equation from the lagrangian?  In other words, should the lagrangian include a term $${\cal L} \supset \bar \phi 
\left[(i\partial_\mu + e A_\mu)\gamma^\mu - m\right] \phi$$that gives rise to the equation of the positron as an Euler-Lagrange equation?  I understand that the positron field $\phi$ can be expressed in terms of $\psi$ using the charge conjugation operator.

Comment: The use of gamma matrices indicates you that you are in presence of a bispinor. The positron is just the two last components of this bispinor.

Comment: WIth due respect, that was not my question.  How does one get the Euler-Lagrange equation for the positron from the lagrangian?